# Python: Reading a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read through a dataframe row by row, and grab what I want out of said row by index. The csv i'm reading in looks something like this...

[image]

but when I read it in, and run this code on it...

```
def sendKafkaMessagesTest(df):
    df.columns = ['Platform_Name', 'Index', 'Type', 'Weapon', 'Munitions', 'Location', 'Tracks', 'Time']
    for ind in df.index:
        data = {'platform_name': str(df['Platform_Name'][ind]),
                'tracks': str(df['Tracks'][ind]), 'time': str(df['Time'][ind])}
        print(data)
        producer.send('numtest', data)
```

It produces this... `{'platform_name': '540', 'tracks': '0', 'time': 'nan'}`

I tried changing the columns which I thought would work, but still a no go. It's like it's not considering Row A to be part of the data or something. Any ideas?

EDIT: Reading CSV file as `df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path)`

EDIT: Expected output is `{'platform_name': 'TSC2_commander', 'tracks': '0', 'time': '0'}`

Comment: How are you reading the csv file ?

Comment: Could you please provide the CSV file as text, so we can reproduce the issue? Also, what's the expected output?

Comment: @Sushanth i've edited my post to answer your question

Comment: @Roy2012 edited my post to answer what I expect the output to be

Comment: @Bob From visual inspection of csv file, ``to_dict(orient='records')`` on dataframe should yield the required output.

Comment: It seems that the issue is with the line     df.columns = ['Platform_Name', 'Index', 'Type', 'Weapon', 'Munitions', 'Location', 'Tracks', 'Time']. You change the names of the columns - so they now refer to the wrong data. Could that be the case?

Comment: @Roy2012 I made that change to try to get to the right data. I assumed that change would work, but I was wrong. For whatever reason, the dataframe is reading in `Column A` as like row names or something

Comment: Could you please attach the actual CSV as text in the question? We can then try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: is there a reason you're just not reading in the entire csv then pulling the data you want?